# Recursively replace string in directory of excel files

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm trying to replace every occurrence of a given string with another string in a directory of excel files.

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(DIRECTORY):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            path = os.path.join(root, file)
            print("Opening: " + path)
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
            for ws in wb.worksheets:
                for row in ws.iter_rows():
                    for cell in row:
                        print(cell.value)
                        if cell.value == target:
                            print("TARGET STRING FOUND")
                            cell.value = replace
                wb.save(wb)
```

I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'` when I run the script.

Thanks for any help

Comment: And what is the problem/error you have?

Comment: @luis.parravicini Sorry I forgot to add my error. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) does not return a sequence of files. It yields (root, dirs, files).

```
for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(".xlsx"):
            path = os.path.join(root, name)
            # the rest of your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
basepath="directory_path"
files = list(filter(lambda x: '.xlsx' in x, os.listdir(basepath)))
for file in files:
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f"{basepath}/file")
    for sheet in wb.worksheets:
        for cell in sheet.iter_rows('C{}:C{}'.format(sheet.min_row,sheet.max_row)):
            print(cell + "\n")
            if cell.value == target:
                cell.value = replace
```